# Find matching values from one column to another column in same table SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

If I have this table:

[image]

I want to use T-SQL to go through each row and find the `EmpID` that corresponds to the `SupervisorID` for each row, and assign the `LastName` of the supervisor to `SupervisorLastName`.

So the result should be:

[image]

I started with this, but I think it is just checking if `SupervisorID` is equal to `EmpID` at the individual row level so it returns nothing.

```
CASE
    WHEN (EmpID = SupervisorID) 
        THEN CAST(LastName AS CHAR(30)) 
END AS SupervisorLastName
```

I guess my first example was misleading because I actually want to create the column `SupervisorLastName`. My example shows that it already exists. Thanks

Comment: Try just joining when you need the supervisor name, or create a VIEW that provides this instead of copying data around your database.

Comment: Please don't provide data as images. That makes the data type of every column `pixel`, makes the people trying to help have to type in your sample data to test their queries, then print their query, photograph it at an odd angle on an old desk and post the resulting image for your benefit. Aside: you might want to remove `SupervisorLastName` from your table and create a `view` that includes it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  t1.EmpID, 
    t1.FirstName,
    t1.LastName,
    t1.SupervisorID,
    t2.LastName AS SupervisorLastname 
FROM #testTable t1 
LEFT JOIN #testTable t2 ON t2.EmpID = t1.SupervisorID
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
  ALTER TABLE TableName
  ADD SuperVisorLastName NVARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;

  UPDATE TB1
  SET SuperVisorLastName = TB2.LastName
  FROM TableName TB1
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName TB2 WHERE TB2.EmpID = 
  TB1.SupervisorID) TB2
```

I would do something like the above just add the column defaulted to null. Then do a cross apply to get the correct last name and update the column. Not copy and pastable but should give you a rough idea of how you could do it.

That being said you already technically know who the supervisor is because of the ID on there. So you do not need to unnecessarily repeat data in your data base.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this?

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.LastName AS SupervisorLastname 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmpID, LastName FROM table1) t2 ON t2.EmpID = t1.SupervisorID
```